# Application window is not fully visible. Why? Help needed to fit it on screen

Tags: 14.04, android, display-resolution, ubuntu-gnome, android-studio

When I run Android Studio, the application window is too huge to fit my 15.6 inch laptop screen. As a result I am not able to look at the submit buttons that are at the bottom of the window. Please help me in finding a workable solution to the problem. Is it possible for me to open Android Studio with a different resolution / window size?

A screenshot of my situation is:
[AndroidStudioScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBdZm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of Alt + F7 will allow you to drag the window more towards the up, ultimately allowing you to look at the submit buttons  at the bottom.